# Dataflow SparkPipelineRunner - any available examples?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Does anybody have a working example(s) of using the Cloudera `SparkPipielineRunner` to execute (on a cluster) a pipeline written using the Dataflow SDK?

I can't see any in the [Dataflow](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK) or [Spark-Dataflow](https://github.com/cloudera/spark-dataflow) github repos.

We're trying to evaluate if running our pipelines on a Spark cluster will give us any performance gains over running them on the GCP Dataflow service.

Comment: Hey Polleyg! Stack is not really the best place to ask for examples, docs, or tutorials on stuff. I am with you that these would be beneficial though. I did a thorough research and I cannot find any examples. The best thing I can think of is to go on the proper documentation page and making a "send feedback" request asking for these to be up. Our team of technical writers will be happy to look into your request. I won't post the same on your question about BigQuery and Dataproc examples, but the same logic applies there as well :).

Comment: In general, for questions that would be off-topic for Stack, I would suggest going to Google Groups here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine and posting a similar request. Since the group is not Stack Overflow, we are okay with what would be off-topic for here. Cheers :)

Comment: The README in spark-dataflow repo seems to give an example invocation of WordCount at https://github.com/cloudera/spark-dataflow#word-count-example , both local and on a cluster. Could you elaborate what else you would like to see in an example?

Comment: It's hardly a detailed example though. What's confusing me is this - with the normal Dataflow runner, I can run my Java app and everything will be uploaded to GCP and executed. Is this the same with the Spark runner, or must one use the 'spark-submit' command (assuming I've spun up a Dataproc cluster and provided the spark://host:port in my app)?

Comment: I haven't used the Spark runner myself, but I've asked its author to shed some light on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are examples for using the Beam Spark Runner at the Beam site: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/.

The dependency you want is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-spark</artifactId>
  <version>0.3.0-incubating</version>
</dependency>
```

To run against a Standalone cluster simply run:

```
spark-submit --class com.beam.examples.BeamPipeline --master spark://HOST:PORT target/beam-examples-1.0.0-shaded.jar --runner=SparkRunner
```